# Rails 6 not saving to db

Tags: postgresql, model, ruby-on-rails-6, stripe-payments

I am trying to save a record to a rails model. I use a postgres13 db as base db.
(following this tutorial: [Stripe Webhooks Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYSLhriIZaA))

When I run the code, the id is returned and if I query the model from the console I can see all records. I do not get any errors in the log.

The problem is, that it is not written into the db table.
What could be the reason for this and how could I fix it?

I try to save the data like this:

```
event = WebhookEvent.create!(webhook_params)
```

the webhook_params is like this:

```
  def webhook_params
    {
      source: params[:source],
      data: params.except(:source, :controller, :action).permit!,
      external_id: external_id
    }
  end
```

the model:

```
class WebhookEvent < ApplicationRecord
  enum state: { pending: 0, processing: 1, processed: 2, failed: 3 }
end
```

And the table definition:

```
class CreateWebhookEvents < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :webhook_events do |t|
      t.string :source
      t.string :external_id
      t.json :data
      t.integer :state, default: 0
      t.text :processing_errors

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :webhook_events, :source
    add_index :webhook_events, :external_id
    add_index :webhook_events, [:source, :external_id]
  end
end
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For reference. It appears to have been a problem with the model.
I regenerated it with a different name and it worked fine.